# Why don't I have objects of type SmartDevices?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I just installed genexus and I want to create an SD object, but in the window to create a new object no object of type SD appears, I added a 'Panel' object but after that it appears:

> warning: the SD application cannot be started because there are no SD core objects present in the knowledge base.

And an IIS error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error Unable to Access Requested Page

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using NET or NETCore core for the “backed” layer.
I mean: Mobile applications have a “frontend” layer (e.g. Java application running on an Android phone) and a “backend” layer. This “backend” layer provides REST services which access Database and return to the “frontend” layer the data.
(This document explains more about "Native Mobile applications" architecture: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14981,Online+Mobile+applications+architecture)

These REST services require the “URL Rewrite” IIS module installed. It seems it is not installed properly.
You can check a guide for this module installation at https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14958,How%20to%20install%20URL%20Rewrite.
Perhaps it’s installed but there is a configuration problem, so this troubleshooting guide could be useful tool.
I hope this information helps you.